# org-capture-goto-target only works after I invoke org-capture

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, spacemacs

I made a custom function that goes to the target of capture:

```
(defun inbox-goto()
  (interactive)
  (org-capture-goto-target "c"))
```

It works well once I invoke `org-capture`, but if I try to use it right after fresh boot, it gives me  "Symbol's function definition is void: org-capture-goto-target".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is that `org-capture` is autoloaded but `org-capture-goto-target` is not.  The simplest way to fix that is probably to insert a `require` into the definition for `inbox-goto`:

```
(defun inbox-goto ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'org-capture)
  (org-capture-goto-target "c"))
```

Comment: That was perfect. Thank you!